# Mailing campaign (Newsletter) emails are in queue but not sent

Tags: email, smtp, odoo, newsletter

I'm using Odoo to send emails/Newsletters to my clients (contacts). But on my Odoo installation, it doesn't send emails.

I go to  -> Marketing -> Mass Mailing. On the top, there are two buttons "Test Mailing" and "send to all". When I do "Test Mailing", I successfully receive emails right in my inbox. But when I do "Send to All", Odoo doesn't send emails. Any idea why?

Thanks,

Abdul

Comment: Check whether the partners you are trying to send mails have checked the opt-out checkbox. For those partners the email will not be sent.

Answer (score 3):

Could you first check the parameters of your "Email Queue Manager"?

Menu : Settings > Technical > Automation > Scheduled actions > Email Queue Manager

You can then see the interval settings and the next execution date.
Hope it helps

Zied

Comment: Thanks Zied, but this is not the problem. The problem seems with server

Answer (score 1):

In most instances, emails are not sent immediately. Instead, Odoo uses a scheduled action to send email.

There are a number of places you can check for your email:

**1. Settings -> Technical -> Email -> Emails**

Here you will find all emails scheduled to be sent on the next execution of the Email Queue Manager. If your emails are there in "outgoing" state, you can click the "play" icon to send it immediately. Or go to the scheduled action mentioned by @ZKH.

If it's not there, and hasn't been sent...

**2. Check your log file**

When Odoo sends an email, an info level output is recorded to the screen and looks like:

2016-04-07 00:44:28,788 24385 INFO [database name] openerp.addons.mail.mail_mail: Mail with ID 23 and Message-Id u'<1459989867.832495927810669.702880028926187-openerp-86-res.users@Name>' successfully sent

If this can't be found, you might find an error message instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the domain alias.

Use your tld and not the default localhost

Comment: You question is terribly unclear. Please elaborate on your problem and post as much relevant information--code, error logs, etc--that may help someone answer your question.